# Apache redirect loses post data

Tags: php, apache

If I use Postman to post directly to a page http://host/folder/start.php all the data is posted correctly

However, if I post to http://host/folder which then directs to start.php the post data is lost

Im not 100% sure how this redirect is happening

I have found these:

```
RewriteRule ^/(de|en|es|pt|fr)/(.*)     /start.php?url=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/(de|en|es|pt|fr)/(.*)     /start.php?url=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/regok(/?)$                    /start.php?regok=1  [NC,L]


<Directory "/FOLDER STRUCTURE/wwwroot">
 Require all granted
 DirectoryIndex start.php
</Directory>
```

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Check if folder has index.php page which redirects to start.php and you can store post data in sessions.

Comment: I could never get index.php to work the only page that can be redirected to is start.php

Comment: Try to prevent user not to post to this folder.

Comment: That’s not an option I have an identity server that has to post here

Comment: Check this link http://ka.lpe.sh/2017/05/04/redirect-request-post-data-using-htaccess/

Comment: This option wont work either because the data is posted to https